# Unity android Session initialization already happened error

Tags: branch.io

I recently upgraded to Branch Unity SDK version 0.6.5 from https://github.com/BranchMetrics/unity-branch-deep-linking-attribution/releases and facing session initialization issues. which was working fine before.

On Android, if when the app opens from a deep link the callback is giving error: "Session initialization already happened. set intent extra, "branch_force_new_session", to true."

I need to retrieve link metadata to display the desired UI. So, I need the link properties.

Anybody faced this before? any fix?

Answer (score 0):

Seams like you are initialising the SDK twice.
Are you initialising it in your onStart() and then trying to read the data with some other function that uses the initSession() method? If so, remove the first initialisation.

If you still have the issue, kindly share your implementation of initialisation and reading of link deeplink data from the link.